# jQuery - comparing an array of objects with a number and append

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, comparison

I want to compare an array of objects with a value passed to the function as an input and append the new object if it is not included.

Here is the example:

```
  function sth(id, name){
   var obj = [{Id: 1, Name: 'test'}, 
            {Id: 2, Name: 'test2'}, {Id: 3, Name: 'test3'}];
       if(obj.indexOf(id) !== -1){ // logic similar to this
         //if not present in obj, then add id, name as an object to obj 
         // array
       }
   }
```

Can someone help me in figuring out if there is an optimized approach to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Array.find

Like this :

```
obj.find (function (elem) {
    return elem.id == id;
});
```

This will return first elem that match your id. Or you can use findIndex to get the index.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
var obj=[{Id: 1, Name: 'test'}, {Id: 2, Name: 'test2'}, {Id: 3, Name: 'test3'}];
console.log(obj);
function sth(id, name){
    var isFound=false;
    for(let i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
        if(id==obj[i].id){
            isFound=true;
            break;
        }   
    }   
    if(!isFound){
        obj[obj.length]={Id:id,Name:name};
    }   
}
sth(4,"test4");
console.log(obj);
```